# Html template compatible with all mail clients

Tags: html, css, email, html-email, vml

I am working on an email template with few action.Can any provide me a simple template which contains a table and a button written using html and css and compatible with all mail clients .i asked this [Html is rendering differently in mail clients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37297413/html-is-rendering-differently-in-mail-clients) but couldn't get any response.

Comment: There is no such template. Simply because not all email clients visualize html content and because many users of those clients that do have that function deactivated due to security issues.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few open-source email templates on GitHub that, with little tweaking, fit this bill:

- [Mailgun Transactional Emails](https://github.com/mailgun/transactional-email-templates)
- [Lee Munroe Responsive Email Template](https://github.com/leemunroe/responsive-html-email-template)
- [Cerberus](https://github.com/TedGoas/Cerberus) (disclaimer: mine)

These are all pretty simple, offer the components you ask for, and have very good compatibility across email clients (including Outlook, Gmail, etc.)

There will always be clients with spotty HTML/CSS support like Lotus Notes and Blackberry, but these give you excellent coverage over popular email clients.